# Kotlin - How to compare generic class with list class

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, jvm

I have a generic class named BaseResponse now I want to extract the actual type "O" from the base-response. I have used the inline function with reified type parameter as defined in kotlin documentation but it is not working. This is my function in which I am passing the base response model and comparing the java class and getting the actual object. But If there is a List type like BaseResponseModel<List> it is always going in the else branch, not in the first comparison of the when statement.

```
inline fun <reified O> getAPIResult(apiResponse: BaseResponseModel<O>): O? {
    val actualResult: O? = try {
        when (O::class.java) {
            List::class.java -> {
                apiResponse.getResponseModel(object : TypeToken<List<O>>() {}.type)
            }
            ArrayList::class.java -> {
                apiResponse.getResponseModel(object : TypeToken<ArrayList<O>>() {}.type)
            }
            else -> {
                apiResponse.getResponseModel(O::class.java)
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
    return actualResult
}
```

so can anyone help me here?

Comment: Give this a shot, i haven't tried it though

when {
O::class is Collection<*> ->
}

or
when {
O:class is Collection -> 
}